# 3 Dimension Integral with Stokes Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

Given a continuously differentiable vector field $v:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ with the property $\nabla\times v=(\arctan(2z),2e^{2z},0)^{\top}$. The Surface $\mathcal{F_a}$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is define with $\mathcal{F}_a=\{(x,y,z)^\top|x^2+y^2\le1,z=a\cdot(1-x^2-y^2)\cdot[\ln{(1+\sqrt[3]{1+x^2})}]+e^{x+\sin{(2y)}}\}$

Prove or disprove that $\int_{\mathcal{F}_a}\nabla\times v\cdot do=0,\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: One of the implications of Stokes theorem is that $\iint \nabla \times F\ dS = \iint \nabla \times F\ dA$ if the surface $A$ and the surface $S$ have the same boundary.

Comment: @DougM The surface $\mathcal{F}_a$ consisted of a blanket and a disk base. So do you mean that if the integral on the disk is zero then the whole integral is zero?